# infinite update loop framework7 vue on v-for computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I am fairly new to vue and I am stumped on this one.  I have the following code to create a display of blog posts within my app.  The first time I view the page everything works great.  If I navigate away and return to the page I receive a "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function".  I checked and there is an infinite loop but I can not solve issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<f7-list media-list>
    <f7-list-item
        v-for="post in sortPosts"
        :title="post.title"
        :subtitle="post.category"
        :text="post.exc"
        :key="post.id"
        :link="'/single/'+post.id+'/'"
    >
        <img slot="media" v-bind:src="(post.img) ? post.img : noImg" width="70" />
    </f7-list-item>
</f7-list>


<script>
import store from '../js/store';
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            noImg:'/static/no-image.svg',
            posts:{},
            blog:{},
            menus:{},
            allowInfinite: true,
            infinitePage:1,
            initial:'Blog'
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        var self = this;
        this.initial = store.state.options.inital_page_type;
        this.posts = store.state.posts;
        if(self.blog.posts_per_page > this.posts.length){ self.loading=false; }
    },
    methods: {
        loadMore() {
            const self = this;
            if (!this.allowInfinite) return;
            this.allowInfinite = false;
            this.infinitePage += 1;
            // Excluded the update script
        }
    },
    computed: {
        sortPosts() {
            const posts = this.posts;
            console.log(posts);
            if(posts.length){
            posts.sort(function(a, b) { return a.sort - b.sort; });
            posts.sort().reverse();
            }
            return posts;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Computed props should NOT mutate data. `posts.sort()` mutates data. A quick fix may be `const posts = [...this.posts]`, that way you sort a copy, and not the original (which triggers the infinite update loop).

Comment: That worked perfect.  If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed props should NOT mutate data. `posts.sort()` mutates data.

A quick fix may be `const posts = [...this.posts]`, that way you sort a copy, and not the original (which triggers the infinite update loop).